# How to achive particular hierarchical query in Oracle

Tags: oracle, hierarchical, connect-by

I have a table that looks like (Oracle 11.2.0.2.0):

```
ParentID    ID       AllowsEntry
NULL        A188     N
A188        1881     Y
NULL        A189     N
A189        1891     Y
1891        189A     Y
```

Business rules allow for non-leaf level elements to have data entry, but I need to report as if they didn't I need to be able query the database to produce output like:

```
ParentID    ID
NULL        A188
A188        1881
NULL        A189
A189        1891_
1891_       189A
```

So basically I need to push down intermediate branches that allow data entry to the leaf level. The new leaves need to roll up to a renamed branch:

```
Old Tree       New Tree
A188           A188         -- remains the same, no data entry at this level
  1881           1881       -- remains the same, data entry allowed at leaf
A189           A189         -- remains the same, no data entry at this level
  1891           1891_      -- this is the level that is wrong
    189A           1891     -- 1891 is push down into a new 1891_ level
                   189A     -- and rolls up into the new level.
                   189B     -- etc.
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Where does `189B` come from?

Comment: There are many more values both at the parent branch level and the lowest leaf levels. This is a simplified example.

Comment: Your example is not consistent between the first query and the last. It's hard to understand what you expect right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to add a leaf element to nodes that have `AllowsEnrtry = 'Y'`. The node element should also be renamed with a trailing underscore.

You can simulate the modified data with a UNION ALL and run the recursive query on this view:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS (
  2     SELECT NULL parentid, 'A188' ID, 'N' allowsEntry FROM dual
  3     UNION ALL SELECT 'A188', '1881', 'Y' FROM dual
  4     UNION ALL SELECT  NULL , 'A189', 'N' FROM dual
  5     UNION ALL SELECT 'A189', '1891', 'Y' FROM dual
  6     UNION ALL SELECT '1891', '189A', 'Y' FROM dual
  7     UNION ALL SELECT '1891', '189B', 'Y' FROM dual
  8  ), leaf_also_nodes AS (
  9     SELECT *
 10       FROM DATA
 11      WHERE allowsEntry = 'Y'
 12        AND ID IN (SELECT parentid FROM DATA)
 13  ), data_plus AS (
 14     SELECT d.parentid,
 15            d.id,
 16            CASE WHEN l.id IS NOT NULL THEN l.id || '_' ELSE d.id
 17            END display_name
 18       FROM DATA d
 19       LEFT JOIN leaf_also_nodes l ON d.id = l.id
 20     UNION ALL
 21     SELECT ID, NULL, ID FROM leaf_also_nodes
 22  )
 23  SELECT rpad(' ', (LEVEL - 1) * 2, ' ') || display_name tree
 24    FROM data_plus
 25   START WITH parentid IS NULL
 26  CONNECT BY (PRIOR ID = parentid);

TREE
-----------------------------------------
A188
  1881
A189
  1891_
    189A
    189B
    1891
```

Comment: That's cool, and works perfectly. Is it possible to write the connect by select statement so it returns the parentid and id with a trailing underscore for the new parent branch? (Please see the second select statement, the one with the underscores, in my original question).

Thanks.

Comment: Sure, add the column `PRIOR display_name` to get the modified `parentid`.

Comment: Ahh. That's cool. I didn't realize you could use the PRIOR keyword in the select statement.